# ESB servicemix Vs WSO2/synapse

Tags: esb, wso2, apache-servicemix, apache-synapse

I am searching for the best 100% open source ESB for the following requirements, after searching I'm confused between Servicemix and WSO2/synapse
1- The requester is mobile app that requires all services to be exposed via REST (JSON objects)
2- Many back end providers (JMS, SOAP, SMTP, LDAP, ...)
3- Provide easy way and flexibility to transform and perform complex business logic
4- Security and Caching
5- Above all easy to learn, use and extend with small learning curve and good tutorials and community support
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I think you can achieve what you want with both of these. You might even want to look at the similar Mule ESB CE which is as well open source.

However, considering you want a flexible solution that is easy to learn, but not limited, then I would go for Service Mix and deploy various Camel routes to it. Camel is, imho, probably the easies and most well documented open source integration engines out there and I really recommend it.

In the end, it's a matter of taste. WSO2/synapse has it's base in web services, and you might feel better there if you are more comfortable with XML standards (including SOAP,BPEL..) than java programming (which is sort of needed in SMX/camel).

Comment: Thanks @Petter, but why you are saying if i'm java programmer then go to SMX, Yes I'm java programmer and of course will be interested in writing any customizations with Java, and I hears that WSO2 has eclipse studio developer and integrates with Spring and other java technologies

Comment: Good, my point is that you might feel more comfortable in SMX w/ Camel than WSO2 as a java programmer. Both are Java focused, and on a high level view they do the same thing - ESB - very good.

Comment: Thanks :), so do you have any idea if I can configure LDAP login as End point service via WSO2

Comment: Not really, LDAP is in the wso2 feature list, but I can't even find a small sample or documentation when googleing. It's stright forward with SMX though, http://camel.apache.org/ldap